# Repository pattern and return types

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, repository, repository-pattern

I am using the repository pattern where I have one repository class per database table. I was wondering how you guys approach queries that only need to return a specific number of columns

For example say I have the following

**Item Table**  (fictional table)

```
ItemId
Name
PurchaseDate
Description
Price
```

In my code I create an object with the fields above called Item.cs (currently not using an orm).

If I have multiple scenarios where I need to return

1. ItemId
2. A combination of PurchaseDate and Name
3. ItemId and price

Which would be the best approach?

1. Get all fields from the items table and return an Item object (1 repo query)
2. Create three queries in Repo and return an Item object for each one
3. Create three queries in Repo and return only what is needed?

Now imagine this scenario with a table with over 10 fields.

Personally, I like option one, but I'm not sure if there is a better way to go about this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I personally use a generic type repository and and have my read `AsQueryable()`

Here's the interface.

```
interface IRepository<T>
{
    void Create(T item);
    IQueryable<T> Retrieve();
    void Update(T item);
    void Delete(T item);
    void SubmitChanges();
}
```

and here's the implementation.

```
public class PersonsRepository : IRepository<Person>
{
    private DataContext dc;

    public PersonsRepository(DataContext dataContext)
    {
        dc = dataContext;
    }

    public void Create(Person Person)
    {
        dc.Persons.Add(Person);
    }

    public IQueryable<Person> Retrieve()
    {
        IQueryable<Person> Person = (from s in dc.Persons
                                       select s);
        return Person.AsQueryable();

    }

    public void Update(Person Person)
    {
        Person _Person = (from s in dc.Persons
                            where s.ID == Person.ID
                            select s).Single();
        {
            _Person.LastLogin = Person.LastLogin;
            _Person.Password = Person.Password;
            _Person.LastUpdate = Person.LastUpdate;
            // Cannot change your username.
        }
    }

    public void Delete(Person Person)
    {
        dc.Persons.Remove(Person);
    }

    public void SubmitChanges()
    {
        dc.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Now if you need to query the repository, you want to do something like this.
<sub>forgive me, the below code is untested and I'm actually more of a VB guy :(

hopefully you get the point</sub>

```
public class PersonsService
{
    private PersonRepository<Person> personRepository;

    public PersonService()
    {
        personRepository = new PersonRepository<Person>();
    }

    public UsablePerson GetPersonByID(int ID)
    {
        UsablePerson person = (from p in personRepository<Person>.Retrieve
                               where p.ID = ID
                               select new UsablePerson { p.FirstName, 
                                                         p.LastName, 
                                                         p.EmailAddress }).FirstOrDefault();

        return person;
    }
}
```

For my purposes, I'm using LINQ on this particular project, but this can be adapted to whatever data layer you like... that's the beauty of a repository layer.

From here I "personally" also have a Service Layer that deals with the nuances of data connection... things like `GetPersonByID` or `GetPeopleSince(DateTime marker)`. This is where I strip out the information that I don't need (IE: passwords) and store the remaining information in either a ViewModel or some other POCO.

Comment: Just to see if I am on the same page. For more specific queries like (GetPersonByID) you return the entire person record from the Repo and then in the service layer strip out all the unneeded information and return just the ID? Could you show an example of this, because this is what I am having a hard time with. I'm not sure if I should create lots of Repo method or just have one that always returns all the table columns (i.e entire row)

Comment: I tried my best from memory... I don't have my IDE in front of me so there's probably a few of errors in the above example. Hopefully you get the picture.

Comment: I like that technique because it cuts down on the number of methods in the Repositories. But, I was always taught that you should only return the columns you need from a database it seems that with a Repository you are always returning an entity type or entity collection. Is that the intent of the Repository pattern? Maybe I am over thinking the database performance impact

Comment: Since the repository `Retrieve` is queriable, you can do exactly what you need... let me do a quick update....

Comment: try my last edit... again, no IDE so I might have missed something minor :-p

Comment: Your example looks good to me :) I guess just a quick yes or no to this question. In the Repository layer is it recommended to always return an entity type or entity collection and then filter in the service layer?

Comment: It's my preference for sure. LINQ to SQL delays the execution as long as possible, so querying at the service layer prevents the repo from querying stuff you don't need. It's not until you call something like `FirstOrDefault()`, `Single()`, `ToList()`, etc that the call to the database actually goes through.

Comment: Oh... That works really well with LINQ to SQL but I'm not using an ORM mapper. I'll probably end up using this technique though

Comment: Nitpick: you should be using constructor injection for your data context if you want to do unit testing. Any time you new up a dependency that isn't part of the bcl, you make your code untestable.

Comment: It is the responsibility of the repository to query and return the domain objects. You are just passing the responsibility of the query into a service to query the data - not a good idea. Suddenly anything to do change what gets queried in your database and the separation of concerns doesn't exist anymore. Where are you testing your queries? Repositories and services and, potentially, other parts of your application if you keep returning IQueryable up the stack. Then the responsibility of the writing queries is no longer well defined within the repositories.

Comment: @Bomboca my reason for the abstraction with IRepository is because I build cross platform applications. Therefore I have a server implementation (using SQL Server && EntityFramework/NHibernate et al) and I have a mobile phone implementation (using SQLIte). Then I inject the repository based on which bit is registered in the DI Container. It's a simple abstraction layer with a purpose.

Comment: @ChaseFlorell I understand that you have a reason which is very apparent in your answer. And I'm sure your stuff will keep working wonders but you didn't argue against my statement that says the query responsibility is no longer well defined in your repository. I'll be happy that at least you have considered the pros/cons of your decisions and if the benefit is greater than the down-side, then so be it. Good luck :)

Answer (score 10):

I add methods to my repositories when I need them in contrast to generic repositories where you get a set of methods no matter if you need them or not.

Returning `IQueryable` is a leaky abstraction.

Take a look at Domain Driven Design (the book) and you'll get a good idea of how well designed repositories should look like.

I've also written a rant about generic repositories: [Generic repositories – A silly abstraction](https://web.archive.org/web/20120304195050/https://blog.gauffin.org/2012/02/generic-repositories-a-silly-abstraction-layer/)

Comment: Agreed, returning an `IQueryable` is doing quite the opposite of what you want a repository to do - it's just being that infrastructural concern right back into your domain layer.

Answer (score 2):

If you think of Domain Driven Design, the fact a single object has different configuration most likely indicates different domains. This does not necessitate a different object for each, but it is a good pattern. One way to achieve this is have a base class ith the minimalist set of properties. You then create more "domain specific" classes that inherit from the base.

As for returning the data, there are a variety of ways of "traffic copping" the flow. Multiple repositories separate out the domains nicely, for example. But this adds complexity (not a good idea unless absolutely needed). I don't like a single repository returning different objects. It is more acceptable if you have some nullable properties (maybe).

I am not fond of LINQ to SQL as a DAL, as @KethiS has suggested, but I work in an Enterprise Environment and LINQ to SQL basically sucks at scale. Using LINQ otherwise is great. Just my two cents.

If you can return one object type, that is better. If the difference in the objects is based on permissions, consider clearing out the data the user should not see. Note, however, this is not as scalable if you are grabbing a large number of objects.

Comment: I tend to only return one object type from the repo, but what is tripping me up is should I always return an Entity object? For example if I have a method called GetEmployeeID, should I return an Employee object with just that field? Or should I return just a employee number? Should I just use a getEmployee method or should I break these into more specific methods in the Repo like GetEmployeeId vs always using GetEmployee?

Answer (score 1):

Why would you return all fields when you actually require only few of them? Select the fields that you really want if you are worried about performance. I'm not a big fan of strictly following a design pattern, maybe you should consider altering the design according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I like Linq-based repositories for this kind of thing. Linq2SQL, MSEF, or Linq2NH would allow you, through the Select() method, to define your column list. You would then receive a domain object or Entity class populated with only what you specified. You can have additional code to map this into a DTO, or just use the domain class knowing that it wasn't fully "hydrated".